# How is saving a long array as reverse hexadecimal numbers faster?

Tags: java, android, performance, hex

I have recently started developing on android platform. I am working on an app and for some clues I was looking at the android's sample music app provided by them.
In the app, at the place where they save the now playing list, they have given an argument which I couldn't understand. The argument and the code is as follows:

```
if (full) {
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();

        // The current playlist is saved as a list of "reverse hexadecimal"
        // numbers, which we can generate faster than normal decimal or
        // hexadecimal numbers, which in turn allows us to save the playlist
        // more often without worrying too much about performance.
        // (saving the full state takes about 40 ms under no-load conditions
        // on the phone)
        int len = mPlayListLen;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            long n = mPlayList[i];
            if (n < 0) {
                continue;
            } else if (n == 0) {
                q.append("0;");
            } else {
                while (n != 0) {
                    int digit = (int)(n & 0xf);
                    n >>>= 4;
                    q.append(hexdigits[digit]);
                }
                q.append(";");
            }
        }
```

where

> mPlayList is an array of **long** numbers

and hexdigits is:

```
private final char hexdigits [] = new char [] {
        '0', '1', '2', '3',
        '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'a', 'b',
        'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
};
```

And then **"q"** is saved in sharedpreferences. In a similar fashion they retrieve the list later using these hexdigits. I would really appreciate if someone can explain the significance of this code snippet. I mean how is this different from using the long values directly to create a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they are doing here is a very simple algorithm to splat out the number as fast as possible. For each digit they need to do:

```
>>
&
append character looked up from array
```

Then additionally once for each number they append a `;` at the end.

Each of these operations is very fast, so the end result is to take the long from memory and put it out in a string in a compact form in about as optimal a way as is possible speed-wise.

It's reverse hexadecimal as the smallest digit is displayed first.

This will be faster than a generic algorithm built into Java although I would be surprised if the savings are significant unless they are saving a LOT of these numbers.

Comment: Specifically, they mask out the bottom 4 bits and write that hex digit (the lower order number) - `int digit = (int)(n & 0xf);` then right shift 4 bits and write out the high number `n >>>= 4;`.  Very fast.

Comment: @TimB Thanks for quick and understandable reply. I was just reading a little about these operations and read that bitwise operations are pretty fast as compared to normal mathematical operations. But I was wondering how much difference would this make if say we have 50 long numbers in the array?

Comment: @Simon Thanks for elaborating it further. Cheers!

Comment: In relative terms I would expect it to be significantly faster. In absolute terms though I would expect the saving to be small as 50 isn't really very many numbers. Really your only way to know is to measure it. Without metrics everything else is speculation.